# Save Form Insert Query

Tags: metamug

My resource file is correct. But When I call the api. I get 500 error. 
I checked the query in SQL Editor it works correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="POST">
        <Desc>Store Billing Information</Desc>
        <Update> 
            insert into billing(CARD_HOLDER_NAME,CARD_NUMBER,EXPIRATION_DATE,EXPIRY_YEAR,PAN_NUMBER,
            SERVICE_TAX_NUMBER,GST_NUMBER)
            values($card-holder-name,$card-number,$expiry-month,$expiry-year,$pan,$servicetax,$gst); 
        </Update>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Special characters except for dot(.) and underscore(_) are not allowed while declaring variables.

## Following are valid variables

```
$test
$this_isa.test_variable
$thisisvalid1
$sois.this1
```

## Following are not

```
$_notavariable
$24
$igot.8
$yes.iam.sure
$areyou._kiddingm
$$ofcourseNot
$thisisfun!!
```